# gripper_action_controller configuration

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using Hydro and I saw that  the ros_controllers package has a gripper controller. I have the wsg_50 gripper and I would like to use it with the gripper action controller but I don't know how to do it. My final idea is to integrate it with MoveIt. Someone could help me?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198264/gripper_action_controller-configuration/) by [smithers](https://answers.ros.org/users/20765/smithers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `gripper_action_controller` supports single-actuator position- or effort-controlled grippers. What you need to do to use this controller is to expose the actuated joint of your gripper to your robot hardware abstraction (`hardware_interface::RobotHW`). The joint should be registered to the `hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface` if it's position-controlled, or to the `hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface` if it's effort-controlled.

A high-level overview of the `ros_control` concepts, including how to expose joint resources to a `RobotHW` instance can be found in the ROSCON 2014 talk ([slides](http://roscon.ros.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ros_control_an_overview.pdf), [video](https://vimeo.com/107507546)).

If you have further, more specific questions, don't hesitate to come back.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2